# Option of using curly braces with if condition in a list

Tags: flutter, dart

Does curly braces '{}' has any significance in *if condition* inside a list.

In flutter I was trying to use if condition with curly braces which throws error but when I removed the curly braces it's working fine.

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Navigator(
        pages: [
          MaterialPage(
              key: ValueKey('appNav'),
              child: SampleList()
          ),


          if(show404){  //Here I'm using curly braces which causes error
            MaterialPage(
              key: ValueKey('404'),
              child: Show404()
            ),
          }

          if(_count != null){
            MaterialPage(
                key: ValueKey('$_count'),
                child: DisplayScreen(count: _count,)
            )
          }


        ],

        onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: you need just: `if(show404) MaterialPage(
key: ValueKey('404'),
child: Show404()
)` - curly braces introduce a `Set`

Comment: The linked question is about `for` instead of `if`, but the same principle applies.

Comment: I don't get this?

Comment: run this for example: `void main() {
final foo = true;
final bar = [
if (foo) {
'hello'
},
'world',
];
print(bar);
print('----');
for (final item in bar) {
print('$item is a ${item.runtimeType}');
}
}` and check the output, then replace `if (foo) { 'hello' }` with `if (foo) 'hello'` and run it again